# La mejor forma de enviar imágenes grandes al servidor en conexiones lentas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagen, angular4, upload

Tengo una aplicación con un frontend en angular 2 y un backend en Ruby on Rails, la cual hace uso de la librería [ng2-img-cropper](https://github.com/web-dave/ngx-img-cropper) para que el usuario pueda recortar la imagen y subirla al servidor.

Esta librería genera un base64 de la imagen que guardo en un array para enviar al servidor.

Actualmente lo que hago es enviar en un POST el array con los base64 de las imágenes recortadas, pero en los casos que las imágenes son grandes y la conexión es lenta, puede tardar hasta 6 minutos en enviar unas 4 imágenes.

Hay una mejor forma de enviarlas al servidor?
Se les ocurre alguna mejora posible?

Gracias.

Comment: Haz probado haciendo el upload de las imagenes asíncrono? algo así como tener un div atadi a una directiva y con este procesar el upload secuencialmente. Encontré esta directiva para procesar el upload de base64 https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload

Answer (score 1):

Podrías enviar algo más pequeño como pueden ser los `blob`

```
dataURItoBlob(dataURI): Blob {
    const byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    const mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    let ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
}
```

basado en la discusión generada en la siguiente [consulta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data) hecha por un usuario de SO.

> With the latter method, we save 1/3 storage space. Why is it more common to store images as base64 in MySQL databases?